# C# read ifc / BIM file serilialize - deserialize

Tags: c#, serialization, ifc

I'm completely new with IFC files.
For my company I need to read IFC files see http://www.kleinhandel.nl/test.ifc for example.
I don't know how to read this in C#. I guess I need to de-serialize it, but how?

I've found this website, but there are no downloads available :(

http://code.google.com/p/ifc-dotnet/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use DDS Viewer to view and program modules to IFC files (using C#). Unfortunately the viewer  doesn't allow write capabilities as yet. But at least you can read and at least you can view and query the model. Additionally, DDS Viewer allows Javascript access to the model.

You can find the tool here: http://www.dds-cad.net/132x2x0.xhtml

Answer (score 6):

I know this is quite an old question but if anybody was interested you can also have a look at [xBIM Toolkit](https://github.com/xBimTeam). You can either use source code or NuGet packages. It implements 100% of IFC2x3 and IFC4 and it provides interfaces to write uniform code for both schemas.

It is .NET, written in C#. Examples and documentation is available [here](http://docs.xbim.net/)

*Disclaimer: I'm one of the developers of xBIM Toolkit.*

Answer (score 1):

See `http://code.google.com/p/ifc-dotnet/source/checkout`. You can check the source out with subversion.

```
svn checkout http://ifc-dotnet.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ ifc-dotnet-read-only
```